# Reset the content of a field in all rows of a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking for a way to reset the data in just one column of my MySQL table. Basically, I have a program that has pictures that people can vote on. The votes are tallied in the row 'votes' and incremented by one every time someone clicks to vote. When a winner is declared, I want all the pictures/data/rows to stay in the table but I want just the 'votes' row to be reset to 0. I don't want to delete the row, just reset the data.

Is this the DELETE function or am I thinking of something else? I wanted to make sure I'm doing this entirely correct before testing it out so I don't mess anything up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You refer to a row 'votes'.  Do you mean a column 'votes'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this perhaps (if the table name is pictures):

`UPDATE pictures SET votes = 0`

This will reset votes to 0 for every row in the database.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! You were first so I'll accept your answer. (I have to wait ten minutes for some reason!)

Answer (score 3):

You **DO NOT** want to use `DELETE`. That will delete your rows. To reset everything back to zero, just use an `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `votes_column`=0;
```

**Note:** This will set EVERYTHING in the votes_column to 0;

Answer (score 0):

update votes column to 0 for all rows

Executing a query like this will do the trick:

```
UPDATE yourTableName SET votes = 0;
```